# Dask: subset (or drop) rows from Dataframe by index

Tags: python, dask

I'd like to take a subset of rows of a Dask dataframe based on a set of index keys. (Specifically, I want to find rows of ddf1 whose index is not in the index of ddf2.)

Both `cache.drop([overlap_list])` and `diff = cache[should_keep_bool_array]` either throw a NotImplementedException or otherwise don't work.

What is the best way to do this?

Comment: The functionality of operations on the index in dask are fairly limited.  For instance, [`Index.difference`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Index.difference.html#pandas.Index.difference) would be the straightforward implementation but its also not implemented.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure this is the "best" way, but here's how I ended up doing it:

1. Create a Pandas DataFrame with the index be the series of index keys I want to keep (e.g., `pd.DataFrame(index=overlap_list)`)
2. Inner join the Dask Dataframe

Answer (score -2):

Another possibility is:

```
df_index = df.reset_index()
df_index = df_index.dorp_dplicates()
```